# What does "Positions are 1 based mean"?

Tags: python, indexing

This is from a codeeval problem:

> Given a number n and two integers p1,p2 determine if the bits in position p1 and p2 are the same or not. Positions p1 and p2 are 1 based.

What does the *Positions p1 and p2 are 1 based* mean?

Comment: I would guess it means that the first bit position is 1, second 2, etc instead of 0, 1..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the first (lowest) bit is bit 1, rather than bit 0.

For instance, if n is 23, p1 is 2, and p2 is 4, then the answer is that the bits are different. because 23 in binary is 10111, in which bit 2 is a 1 while bit 4 is a 0.

If the position numbers were instead 0-based, as is pretty common, then the answer would be that the bits are the same, because both bits 2 and 4 in that scheme are 1's.

```
POSITIONS, 1-BASED:   5 4 3 2 1        # bit 4 is a 0 and bit 2 is a 1
            VALUES:   1 0 1 1 1
POSITIONS, 0-BASED:   4 3 2 1 0        # bit 4 and bit 2 are both 1's
```

Comment: so  I use ((int(line1[0]) >> p1 - 1)&1) to allow for the 1 based positions?

Comment: Sure, `(n >> (p1-1)) & 1` will get you the value of bit `p1` within `n` using the 1-based counting.